# Achieve ease in ease out in Vector3 Lerp

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am moving my camera from origin to destination, it all works well but the problem is that there is no smooth ease in/out from origin to destination. How do I achieve a smooth ease in when camera is travelling and smooth ease out when the camera reaches the destination?
It is necessary to have totalMovementTime as I want my camera to reach the destination in given seconds.

```
public IEnumerator MoveToDestination () {

        float totalMovementTime = 2f; 
        float currentMovementTime = 0f;
        while (Vector3.Distance (transform.localPosition, destinationCamPos) > 0) {
            currentMovementTime += Time.deltaTime;
            transform.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp (transform.localPosition, destinationCamPos, currentMovementTime / totalMovementTime);
            yield return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the AnimationCurve for "easy" easing :)
Create a serialized field in your script of type AnimationCurve.
In inspector play with it making the desired easing curve (there are also ready to use presets).
Then for the step (progress) of your lerp you need to "evaluate" using your curve
[AnimationCurve.Evaluate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationCurve.Evaluate.html)
Make sure your are using the normalized value for the Lerp progress.

```
[SerializedField] AnimationCurve curve;
...
var normalizedProgress = currentMovementTime / totalMovementTime ; // 0-1
var easing = curve.Evaluate(normalizedProgress);
transform.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp (transform.localPosition, destinationCamPos, easing);
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. I know that this can be achieved with animation, but I was hoping to use it without any animation.

Comment: AnimationCurve is not animation, it is just an easing function that you can "tweak" in inspector

Comment: I tried it but the camera is jittering while moving. 2 of the curves are causing jitter. How to overcome this?

Comment: Debug your code, during the motion the normalized progress must be alweys in range from 0 to 1. Try to make your curve a linear slope from 0 to 1, the evaluation of the curve should return the same result as input (linear movement). Then try to make an "S" shape curve to smooth out the acceleration/deceleration.